# Listener is not starting in my Standby database

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, listener, dataguard, tnsnames

I'm facing a serious issue in data guard installation. I'm setting oracle_sid and oracle_home and when I start the listener,error is showing as below:

```
C:\Windows\system32>lsnrctl start
LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production on 31-MAY-2017 16: :38
Copyright (c) 1991, 2013, Oracle. All rights reserved.
Starting tnslsnr: please wait...
Failed to start service, error 0. TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
```

Solutions which I have tried:

1. I've set the correct path in environment variables which is in System Properties.
2. I've given correct IP address in Hostname(listener.ora)

But still nothing could help me out....It's urgent

Comment: Try two other things: restart the listener service. If that doesn't works, you have to check the logs to get more detail.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try the below,

1. run the cmd as administartor and verify the ORACLE_HOME and PATH variable and try lsnrctl start
2. If it still fails to start, provide listener.ora file